# Why doesn't "where AND" work using EloquentFilter?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm using EloquentFilter in my laravel project.

I have a table have with columns **First_name**, **Mid_name**, **Las_name**, **Type**, **Status**.

Below are the sample values:
[image]

And these are my filters:

```
public function name($name){
    return $this->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
        ->orWhere('mid_name', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
        ->orWhere('las_name', 'LIKE', "%$name%");
}

public function isAvailable(){
    return $this->where('status', 1);
}

public function thisType(){
    return $this->where('type', 2);
}

public function setup(){
    $this->thisType();
    $this->isAvailable();
}
```

Here's the **model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\ModelFilters\AdminFilters\UserFilter;
use EloquentFilter\Filterable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use Filterable;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'mid_name',
        'las_name',
        'type',
        'status'
    ];

    # Other

    public function modelFilter()
    {
        return $this->provideFilter(UserFilter::class);
    }
}
```

So if I use, `User:filter(Input::all())->get();`, automatically 2 results will be returned, because of the fixed value(2) of **type column**.

But my problem is when I search for "a" then 5 results are returned. Why does it return 5 results when they don't all have a 2 value in the **type column**?

I suspect its functioning as `->orWhere` when it returns 5 results. Can anyone help me figure out this problem?

Comment: Can you post the full code of the model and where you are using this? That makes it much easier to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Where is the code where you do something like `$user->name()` ?

Comment: @DmitriChebotarev actually I'm using it in ajax but for testing purposes I type in URL like for example when I `localhost:8000/users/show` it shows 2 datas. but when I `localhost:8000/users/show?name=a` it display 6 datas.

Comment: @DmitriChebotarev if you mean inside my controller that I used, one line only inside my controller `return User::filter(Input::all())->get();`

Comment: It looks like all of your records in the screenshot have an `a` in the firstname, lastname and middle name. So that seems correct.

Comment: @DmitriChebotarev yeah but the value that I specified in **type column** is 2, why all datas are returned when not all has a **type value** of 2

Comment: What's the value of `Input::all()`?

Comment: @DmitriChebotarev in my URL `localhost:8000/users/show?name=a` there one field that is **name** that has value **a**. I'm using a GET method in my ajax actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you are using this package:
https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter

So what you are doing with the `setup()` method is correct.
But the `orWhere()` makes is it so that the type either has to be 2 or any of the names have to contain an`a` and since all the names match this it will return 6 records everytime.

The fix is quite easy, you just need to wrap your `orWhere()` queries inside a `where()`:

```php
public function name($name){
    return $this->where(function ($query) use ($name) {
        return $query->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
        ->orWhere('mid_name', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
        ->orWhere('las_name', 'LIKE', "%$name%");
    });
}
```

This will tell that you want the type to be 2 AND the either of the names to contain an `a`

Hope this solves you issue!